# Meteor JS and State (address) select element

Tags: meteor, html-select

I want to have a state select in meteorjs for an address input field. I feel like listing out all the states in a massive html string of `<option>`s is wrong. Is there a documentation or preferred way to do this?

In frameworks like CakePHP, I would create a DB table related to address and just use the form helper methods to output the markup based on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd prefer to fetch a set of states from a database, you could create a Meteor Collection to store them.

```
States = new Mongo.Collection("states");
```

If you've removed the `autopublish` package (which if you haven't, [you should](https://www.meteor.com/try/11)), you need to then publish this collection,

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("states", function() {
    return States.find();
  }
}
```

and then subscribe to it, and make it available to your template with a helper:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("states");

  Template.myForm.helpers({
    states: function() {
      return States.find();
    }
  });
}
```

Then you can output the collection in your template as such:

```
<select>
  {{#each states}}
    <option>{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

A nice way to enter the data into the database is through the Meteor Mongo shell or through a GUI like [RoboMongo](http://pem-musing.blogspot.nl/2014/04/robomongo-ultimate-graphic-admin-tool.html)